# iOS generate PDF file with one image on each page

Tags: ios, uigraphicscontext, cgcontextref

I found this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) that describes how to add content to the PDF. So as I understood right the pages will be generated based on input NSString. So the count of pages depends on the length of the string.

I need to implement the same but with the images. So for example I have 10 images, and all of them will be places on by one on each page. Like first image on the first page, second images on the second page and etc.

I found also this [library](https://github.com/maor10/PDF/blob/master/PDF.m) that can generate PDF files but seems I don't have chance to set count of pages. Is there any good solution how to implement it?

Comment: Why you don't use CGPDFContextBeginPage to create the page and then draw the new content in the PDF context?

Comment: @viggio24 sorry never used it. just started.

Comment: @viggio24 I can't understand how we can for example create at least 2 pages

Comment: @viggio24 oh seems I understood how to make it so I just need to create 2 CGPDFContextBeginPage for 2 pages

Comment: yes, that's right. don't forget to call CGPDFContextEndPage() before creating a new page.